# Dynamic has_many through creation with tagging select2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I have a recipe model that has_many equipment through recipe equipment set up like below:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_equipment, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :equipment, through: :recipe_equipment
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_equipment
end

class Equipment < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :recipe_equipment
    has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_equipment
end

class RecipeEquipment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :equipment
end
```

All pretty straight forward there.  Then in my recipe form Im using select2 with the tags option enabled here is the input for that:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :equipment_ids, "Equipment Needed" %>
  <%= form.collection_select :equipment_ids, Equipment.all.order(:name), :id, :name, {:selected => recipe.recipe_equipment.map(&:equipment_id)}, { multiple: true } %>
</div>
```

And the standard select2 initialization:

```
$('#recipe_equipment_ids').select2({
    width: '100%', 
    maximumSelectionLength: 10,
    tags: true});
```

So this all works as expected except when a new equipment is inputted, it is submitted as text instead of an id (since the equipment hasnt been created yet and doesnt have an ID)

```
"equipment_ids"=>["", "7", "3", "Wok"]
```

So looking for a way to process parameters array before calling the create/update in the controller and create the new equipment if it doesnt exist yet.  Not sure how to go about that though.

Comment: It should be `has_many :recipe_equipments` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_equipments`. `has_many` associations should always be in plural.

Comment: Equipment is the plural of equipment

Comment: Yeah, your right. (facepalm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured this out right after I posted, but figured Id post the answer for others.  Also this might not be the best solution but it does get the job done and limits additional queries on the database

So I ended up override the default accessor for the equipment_ids in the recipe.rb file.  since it comes thru as a mix of potential integers and strings check to see if it isnt an integer already then use the find_or_create_by! method to create a new equipment with the name.  Then pass the new id to an array and pass that to the super.

```
def equipment_ids=(value)
  equip = []
  value.reject!(&:empty?).each do |e|
    equip << (e.to_i != 0 ? e : Equipment.find_or_create_by!(name: e).id)
  end  
  super(equip)
end
```